# Embed Powershell prompt in Windows 7 desktop

Tags: windows, powershell

On Linux (last time I did this was with Compiz on Ubuntu 11), I like to have a transparent console window anchored to the desktop, so I can get to a shell just by clicking out of whatever I'm doing and don't have to play with with moving/resizing windows.

I'd like to do something similar on Windows 7/Server 2008.  I could probably write up a quick little app in .Net that would run fullscreen and have a powershell terminal embedded in it, but, if somebody has already created something sufficient, or there is some other hackery to do this, I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Another possibility could be a Quake-style pulldown console, similar to Guake ([guake.org](http://guake.org)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using ConEmu, which supports a Quake-style dropdown console.  http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/

Comment: It's the best console for Windows. Hands down.

Answer (score 2):

I use Console2 ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/ ) for this.  You can remove title bar, pin it to the desktop, set transparency, etc.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PoshConsole has this. http://poshconsole.codeplex.com/